# How to use pause for each level in a forest tree?

Tags: beamer, forest, pause

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer} 
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
my nodes/.style={minimum height=1.5cm,rounded corners,draw,align=center,top color=white,bottom color=A!80}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
\tiny
\scalebox{0.7}{\begin{forest}
for tree={s sep=(3-level)*2mm,my nodes,s sep=0.1cm,child anchor=north, l+=.5cm},
for level=2{tier=A,minimum height=1cm, anchor=north},
for level=3{tier=B, minimum height=1.3cm, anchor=north,l+=. 3cm}
[{The maximum number of limit cycles of the DPDS \\ $(0.1)-C_{k}$ with $k=i,ii,iii,iv$}
[ {$ C_{i} $ i.e.,\\ $C=a=0$}
[{$A+b=0$}[{6\\ limit cycles}]][{$A+2b=0$ \\ or $Ab(A+2b)(A+b)\neq 0$}[{4\\ limit cycles}]][{$b=0$}[{3\\ limit cycles}]][{$A=0$ or $A=b=0$}[{2\\ limit cycles}]]
]
[ {$ C_{ii} $ i.e.,\\ $b+d=0$ }
[{$A+b=0$}[{3\\ limit cycles}]][{$A=0$ or $b=0$ or \\  $\Delta\geq 0$}[{3\\ limit cycles}]][{$A=b=0$}[{3\\ limit cycles}]][{$\Delta<0$}[{\,\,\,\textbf{?}\,\,\,}]]
]
[ {$ C_{iii} $ i.e.,\\ $a-2b=C+2a=0$ }[2\\ limit cycles]
]
[ {$ C_{iv} $ i.e.,\\ $C+2a=A+3b+5d=$\\ $a^2+bd+2d^2=0$ }[8 \\ limit cycles]
]
]
\end{forest}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @user202729: I think OP wants the tree to appear level-by-level in beamer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: yes I wants the tree to appear level-by-level in beamer

Comment: Or alternatively: [How can I use \pause for each level in beamer presentation to appear sequentially?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/313720)